# Oracle 12C DB Link to Hive

Tags: oracle, hive, dblink

I created a database link to Hive following the article
[How To Query Hive and Impala from Oracle using ODBC Heterogeneous Gateway](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-1002634).

```
select count(*) from customers@HIVEDSN;
```

isql works fine, but in SQL*Plus I get an error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[
```

Here is the trace log:

```
--------------------------------------------
Entered hgopoer at 2017/05/19-03:08:29
hgopoer, line 240: got native error 10210 and sqlstate H; message follows...
[
Exiting hgopoer, rc=0 at 2017/05/19-03:08:29
hgolgon, line 202: calling SQLSetConnectAttr got sqlstate H
Exiting hgolgon, rc=28500 at 2017/05/19-03:08:29 with error ptr FILE:hgolgon.c LINE:202 ID:Connection Attribute: TRACE
hostmstr:          0: HOA After hoalgon
RPC Calling nscontrol(0), rc=0
```

Comment: That does not look like a trace log from the Cloudera ODBC driver, cf. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Impala-ODBC-impala-odbc-reports-invalid-connection-string/td-p/34890

Comment: Also, https://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Enterprise-Assets-Data-Sources/Unable-to-connect-to-Cloudera-Hadoop-from-MSTR-v9-4-1/td-p/246949 suggests that the `10210` message is just a warning; either it masks the actual error because Oracle cannot display the whole stack _(so you must get the error from the ODBC trace)_, or SQL*Plus fails on a mere warning _(and in that case try another tool e.g. Oracle SQL Developer)_

Comment: You can also try to compare configuration files against a tutorial I wrote for the commercial [DataDirect Cloudera Hive ODBC driver](https://www.progress.com/blogs/instant-oracle-big-data-apps-with-database-gateway-for-odbc-to-hadoop-hive). Disclaimer: I work for Progress.